# Unable to complete the code coverage if the conditional statement is in Jquery - Jasmine - AngularJs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jasmine, code-coverage, karma-runner

My project is written in angular and test cases in Jasmine. These test cases are run with Karma.

I have a scope function in the controller that has a if condition in it. This if condition statement is in Jquery. I am not sure how to test the if and else part of this code.

```
$scope.getHelperMessage = function(type, target) {  
        $scope.helperMessageHidden = false;     
        $(target).addClass("icon-selected");

        if (type === "password") { // this if condition is covered when I pass type as "password" in the fn args
            $scope.helperMessage = passwordInfoMsg;
        } else if (type === "personal") {
            $scope.helperMessage = personalNumberInfoMsg;
        } else if (type === "email") {
            if ($(".email-wrapper .error-icon").css('display') === 'none') { // this if condition is not covered as i dont know how to set this statement in my test case
                $scope.helperMessageHidden = true;
            } else {
                $(".form-message-container p").html(alreadyRegisteredInfoMsg);
            }               
        }
    }
```

Here is my test case for the above scope function

```
describe('on focus of any input field', function() {    

        it('should show the password helper message', inject( function(passwordInfoMsg){ 
            var type = "password";
            var target = ".password-wrapper .info-icon";            
            scope.getHelperMessage(type, target);
            expect(scope.helperMessageHidden).toBe(false);
            expect(scope.helperMessage).toBe(passwordInfoMsg);
        }));    

        it('should show the personal number helper message', inject( function(personalNumberInfoMsg){ 
            var type = "personal";
            var target = ".personal-wrapper .info-icon";
            scope.getHelperMessage(type, target);
            expect(scope.helperMessageHidden).toBe(false);
            expect(scope.helperMessage).toBe(personalNumberInfoMsg);    
        }));    

        it('should show the already exists email helper message', inject( function(alreadyRegisteredInfoMsg){ 
            var type = "email";
            var target = ".email-wrapper .error-icon"; // here I dont know how to set the value for if condition            
            scope.getHelperMessage(type, target);
            expect(scope.helperMessageHidden).toBe(false);
        }));
});
```

[image: Screenshot of the code coverage for this scope function]

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just set the `display` manually?

```
    it('should hide the already exists email helper message', inject( function(alreadyRegisteredInfoMsg){ 
        var type = "email";
        var target = ".email-wrapper .error-icon";
        $(target).css({display: 'none'}); // Set display manually      
        scope.getHelperMessage(type, target);
        expect(scope.helperMessageHidden).toBe(true);
    }));
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Even if I set it manually its not getting into the if condition

Comment: You should make sure that there's an `.email-wrapper` with nested `.error-icon` in the body before running this test. What does `console.log( $(target)[0], $(target).css({display'}) );` output? (insert it before `scope.getHelperMessage(type, target);`). — Normally, you'd put DOM interaction in directives, because it makes testing easier, but I guess in your case an `ng-hide` would be more appropriate than what you're doing now.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to, for the sake of the test, override the jQuery css function with a mock to return the value you want? For example:

```
it('should show the already exists email helper message', inject( function(alreadyRegisteredInfoMsg){ 
    var type = "email";
    var target = ".email-wrapper .error-icon";
    $.fn.css = function() {return "none";}; //make $(...).css(...) === "none"
    scope.getHelperMessage(type, target);
    expect(scope.helperMessageHidden).toBe(false);
}));
```